# Are Cataloge and relation cache in PostgreSQL per connection or global to the server?

Tags: postgresql, cache, relations, catalogs

I am trying to figure out if Postgres' relation and catalog cache are per connection or per server? I did find that plan caches are per connection. It would make sense for the cache to exist for as long as the server is running, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is catalog and relation cache kept in shared memory or in session memory?

Both.

All relations in PostgreSQL are cached in shared memory up to the limit configured by [`shared_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html) parameter. This includes also system catalog (`pg_class`, `pg_attribute`, etc).

When a session is running, it builds its own internal cache in private memory for many things - including query plans, name-oid mappings etc.

On query level you can review caching effect with EXPLAIN command - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908530/540341).

On global level you can inspect contents of shared buffers using a standard extension named [`pg_buffercache`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbuffercache.html).

Also, if we speak about caching you can't ignore the O/S filesystem caching machinery. See [this excellent presentation](https://momjian.us/main/writings/pgsql/performance.pdf).

---

Answer (score 2):

Those caches are per connection.  They are not held in shared memory.

Comment: It is not possible to share it among connections? Is there any config param?

Comment: No, no server config to allow that.  You can use a connection pooler, which will allow virtual connections to share a real connection, so can get sharing that way.

Comment: @jjanes But if `pg_class` lives in shared buffers then we can say it's cached, right?

Comment: But pg_class is not the catalog cache.  It is part of the catalog itself.  I guess you could say that whatever pages of it happen to be shared_buffers are cached, but they are just copies of disk pages, not in their parsed form.  I was taking "catalog cache" to refer to the specific thing from the source, e.g. src/include/utils/catcache.h

Comment: @jjanes yup the question was not very clear.... but I assumed the generic meaning of "cache" term, which can mean both shmem AND private set. The code manifested in catcache.h also (indirectly) uses shmem...